# Git: How to make a merge commit with an arbitrary known end-state

Tags: git, git-merge

For reasons, I need to restructure the (local) history of some commits including a merge commit. And I'd rather not repeat the merge conflict resolution process.

I already have a commit that represents the state that the final merge commit state should look like, and I'd like to set up the 2 parent commits and then tell git:

> Look, just trust me ... there should be a commit with merge parents `A` and `B`, but where the codebase looks like `C` ... so don't worry about attempting to actually merge `A` and `B` together.

If I were rebasing I would know how to do this, with history manipulations, but I don't know how to do that when the history includes commits with multiple parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what `git commit-tree` can do. Suppose the final **tree** of the merge commit you want is on commit `X`, and the parents of the desired new commit are `P1` and `P2`, then this can be done:

```
git commit-tree -p P1 -p P2 -m "Some comment" X^{tree}
```

That will print the ID of a commit that has `P1` and `P2` as parents (in that order) and the tree just like `X`. Feel free to check it out, `git log` it and, when you are sure that is what you like, place a branch on it.

If you feel more comfortable without the hackish stuff, you could try to run the merge, which will lead to n conflicts.... and then use `git restore --worktree --staged --source=X -- .` which should work just as beautifully in getting the final tree you wish ready for you to wrap up the merge.